# Numpy conditional arithmetic operations on two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, conditional-statements

Still trying to earn my numpy stripes: I want to perform an arithmetic operation on two numpy arrays, which is simple enough:

```
return 0.5 * np.sum(((array1 - array2) ** 2) / (array1 + array2))
```

Problem is, I need to be able to specify the condition that, if both arrays are element-wise 0 at the same element `i`, don't perform the operation at all--would be great just to return 0 on this one--so as not to divide by 0.

However, I have no idea how to specify this condition without resorting to the dreaded nested for-loop. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

**Edit**: Would also be ideal not to have to resort to a pseudocount of +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `np.sum()` by [`np.nansum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html#numpy.nansum):

```
return 0.5 * np.nansum(((array1 - array2) ** 2) / (array1 + array2))
```

`np.nansum()` treats `nan`s as zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
return numpy.select([array1 == array2, array1 != array2], [0.5 * np.sum(((array1 - array2) ** 2) / (array1 + array2)), 0])
```

should do the trick... `numpy.where` might also be used.

Comment: This is an excellent idea (didn't know I could do this), but shouldn't it be `numpy.select([array1 == 0.0 and array2 == 0.0, array1 != array2], ...)` for the first condition?

Comment: Yes, I didn't catch that the first time. You can do (array1 == 0) * (array2 == 0) for the first condition. However, Sven's solution seems even better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try post-applying `numpy.nan_to_num`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

although I found that when I have a divide by zero in your code, it gives a warning, but fills that element with zero (when doing integer math) and NaN when using floats.

If you want to skip the sum when you have a divide by zero, you could also just do the calculation and then test for the `NaN` before returning:

```
xx = np.sum(((array1 - array2) ** 2) / (array1 + array2))
if np.isnan(xx):
    return 0
else:
    return xx
```

**Edit:** To silence warnings you could try messing around with `numpy.seterr`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

Comment: This is very good suggestion. My only complaint here is that I'd still have to silence the cascading warnings when a divide-by-zero occurs.

Comment: @Magsol: Why are there warnings?  NumPy should actually divide by zero without complaining, and just yield NaN.

Comment: @Sven: I believe the warning is new as of numpy 1.5

Comment: No messing around is needed, just `old_setting= np.seterr(divide= 'ignore')` should be enough. Thanks